# Key/value store for random data sampling

Tags: java, random, nosql

For the moment to generate random data for testing I stream my data, then I shuffle the stream and take the first n elements. But I was thinking about storing the data in a local lightweight key/value store. Is there one that allows to shuffle the key in the cache or at a low level? Is there another way to do this? My goal is to have a low level function that generates random samples in a fairly unbiased manner without taking too much memory.

Comment: What do you mean with "shuffle the key in the cache"?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017338/how-do-you-shuffle-elements-in-a-map

Comment: If you really want more than just a `HashMap`, you can for example try redis and https://redis.io/commands/randomkey or sth based on https://redis.io/commands/srandmember

Comment: @Ben I meant to shuffle them as soon as I access them. I don't even know whether I want to put a cache in between just making some hypotheses.

Comment: @Zapl Thank you. I'll try it, that maybe the answer I was looking for.